# Update table with column duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table name = tblnames

name            id          sno

Mary            mary        1
John            john        2
Sophia          sophia      3
Ava             ava         4
Mary            mary1       5
John            john1       6
John            john2       7
John            john3       8
Sophia          sophia1     9
Emma            emma        10
Sherlock        sherlock    11
```

I already have id column generated by 
update tblnames set id = lower(name)
The problem is when the name is same the id is also same.

I want to create id column from name column such that shown above.
It appends 1, 2, 3 if the name is already exists in column.

I want the id to be appended with 1, 2, 3 when same name exists. 
For example in table above the mary on 5th row should be mary1
6th row should be, john1
7th row should be, john2
and so on

I have a table of 2 Million Rows. 
Please suggest a mysql query only. My database is in mysql.

How can I update my email column with sql as fast as possible. 
I tried with php it takes too long when the table contains million rows. 
Thanks

Comment: you're not going to be able to do this easily in pure sql. plus... IDs generally should be a straight integer value, e.g. an `auto_increment` value in mysql, in which case you have a unique number for EVERY record already.

Comment: **Why do you want to do this?**  If you're happy for the `id` to be synthetic (by having a meaningless numeral postpended), then why not have an entirely synthetic `id` of a number alone?  If `id` needs to be natural, then you will need to determine some *identifying* property of `tblnames` (i.e. one that is unique to each record).

Comment: added one serialno column. is it possible to do now with sql query. The tblnames has 2 Million rows therefore looking for mysql query. PHP code is taking 2 hours to get it done

Comment: You'd be far better to generate a unique ID (say, in uuid format) and use that instead. Then you only need double check that the ID hasn't already been used, and voila.